# Unregister PushNotificationTrigger background task in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

I have a `BackgroundTask` registered and declared in `package.appmanifest`. It is `PushNotificationTrigger` task that triggers only when it receives raw push notification and shows Toast.

I need to unregister this `BackgroundTask` while closing my app.

I have tried the following code snippet but this didn't unregister my `BackgroundTask` and still receives raw push notification and shows toast.

```
var entry = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(keyval => keyval.Value.Name == "MyBackgroundTask");
            if (entry.Value != null)
            {
                entry.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
```

I tried another approach. But that doesn't worked too.

```
foreach (var iter in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                IBackgroundTaskRegistration task = iter.Value;
                if (task.Name == "MyBackgroundTask")
                {
                    task.Unregister(true);
                }
            }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the problem? Enumerating *AllTask* and finding by *Name* or *EntryPoint* does not work?

Comment: I'm receiving toast notification even if I unregistered backgroundtask. Toast notifications are supposed to show only when the push notification is received. That means I have registered one background task that triggers when push notification is received. Please see the edited question.

Comment: You have said that you have two *BackgroundTasks*, but you are unregistering only one. What are the names/entry points of those tasks? Are you registering the [push notification task like this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709906.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, one background task triggers when push notification is received. Problem is when I unregister it, it still receives raw notification in background and shows toast notification.

Comment: I'm bit lost - your title says Unregister two background tasks - which shouldn't be a problem. As you say there is a problem that when you unregister the task responsible for notification, it's still working. Have you checked if it's unregistered successfully? You have mentioned that when you have only one task, then it works - what does it mean?

Comment: Hello @Ramasz sorry for the mess. I edited my question again, so please have a look on it and hope you will got my point. My requirement is that my app shouldn't receive raw notifications when *PushNotificationTrigger* is unregistered.  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88495/discussion-between-kishor-bikram-oli-and-romasz).